# Python modules I've just installed in my virtual env, are not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pip, virtualenv

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS. Output of `python3 --version` command: *Python 3.8.10*
When I type `pip` in terminal and press TAB, it responds with the following options: **pip**, **pip3**, **pip3.10** and **pip3.8**

But, when I use any of then with the `--version` flag, it all prints the same output, which is: **pip 22.3.1 from /home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)**

When I use "pip list" command, I can see the *"virtualenv"* package version(which is 20.17.0)

Then I create my virtual environment using this following command: `python3 -m venv .env`

Then I activate it using `source .env/bin/activate` command

Before installing the modules, I update virtual environment's pip, using the following command:

```
.env/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Also, I have a file called *requirements.txt* with the packages names I need in it:

```
wheel
numpy
matplotlib
sklearn
seaborn
```

So I install them using the following command:

```
.env/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir --use-pep517
```

Finally, I try to run my python program using *".env/bin/python kmeans3.py"* command, it prints this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kmeans3.py", line 10, in <module>
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

obs: This is the first 12 lines of the file:

```
"""
.env/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
.env/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir --use-pep517
"""

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans 
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
```

Comment: After `source .env/bin/activate`, your environment variables are modified so you shouldn't need to prepend paths to your python commands. After activating the virtual environment, if you `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt` and then `python kmeans3.py`, does it work?

Comment: No, it doesn't, I've tried both ways.

Comment: If you create a new user on your machine, and then try it, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Looks ok to me.
If your environment is activated try to just run

```
python kmeans3.py
```

or

```
python3 kmeans3.py
```

Comment: Still print the same error

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why is that, but I solved this problem installing *"scikit-learn"* package before install *"sklearn"*

Comment: Good catch!  FYI, [`pip install sklearn` has been deprecated - use `pip install scikit-learn` instead](https://pypi.org/project/sklearn/).